# Strange Code coverage

Tags: deployment, upload

I got in some strange situation. When I'm trying to upload package to sandbox it says that I have only 71% of code coverage and when I check it in setup it says 79%. What can cause it?
[image: Coverage in upload]

[image: Coverage in classes]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a known issue mentioned here https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5k3AAC

Its fix is in process. You can track it in above link. However, it is being fixed on several instances.

Workaround is create test class individually for all main classes. Don't expect classes to cover from other test class.